# react-jss does not cache css classes

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, jss

I use Mui (material ui) List and in the ListItem I have a custom component that's a bit complex (has other components + states, can collapse or expand, etc.).

I use react-jss (injectSheet(styles)(component)), and I see that for every element that I am adding in the list, there is a new Css that's injected into the page header.
I thought that there is a caching added in react-jss but it looks that I was wrong.

Could you please advice how can I cache the Css using react-jss? Also, if this is not an option, and I have to use jss + plugins then an example of jss setup with caching plugin will help.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Static styles injected through react-jss are reused between all component instances. If you use function values (dynamic styles) there will be no reuse as you can have different values on each element.